# Request caching OKHttp 3.o or any other solution

Tags: java, android, rest, http, okhttp

I am writing an application that requires end user to constantly send updates to our server. I generally use the OKhttom or httpURLConnec clients to make me api calls.

The api call is tied to a button click.

In case my end user has no internet access, is it possible that if he clicks the button to make the request. The request is cached and made later on automagically whenever internet is available?

Answer (score 0):

I can think you can read the Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html) and choose the best option for you like:

- [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager) - [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager)
- [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) (only for API 21+) [example](https://developer.android.com/samples/JobScheduler/index.html)

> Evernote has released a library which already switch to the best implementation available for the device, i would suggest you to use this without doing everything from scratch: https://github.com/evernote/android-job